# Bootstrap parent unstyled list where each element has nested inline list inline with parent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I get a Bootstrap parent un-ordered list `<ul class="list-unstyled"></ul>` with un-ordered inline nested child lists `<ul class="list-inline"></ul>`

I want end result to look like this:

parent element 1 - child element 1, child element 2

parent element 2 - child element 1, child element 2, child element 3, child element 4

parent element 3 - child element 1, child element 2, child element 3

etc

Right now I have:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li>parent element
        <ul class="list-inline">
                <li>child element</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Which produces

parent element 1

child element 1, child element 2

parent element 2

child element 1, child element 2, child element 3, child element 4

parent element 3

child element 1, child element 2, child element 3

etc

What needs to change to make the child lists be inline with parent list elements?

Answer (score 1):

Added

```
 .list-unstyled li{
     display: flex !important;
     padding-left: 10px;
 }

.list-inline{display: flex !important;}
```

```css
.list-unstyled li{
 display: flex !important;
 padding-left: 10px;
}

.list-inline{display: flex !important;}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li>parent element 1
        <ul class="list-inline">
                <li>child element 1.1</li>
                <li>child element 1.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>parent element 2
        <ul class="list-inline">
                <li>child element 2.1</li>
                <li>child element 2.2</li>
                <li>child element 2.3</li>
                <li>child element 2.4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: When code snippet is run here the elements are wrapping within their element when window width is reduced. A regular list would wrap entire line, not each element. Also when I implement on my side, the list width is expanding past my page width producing scrollbar at bottom. That must be effect of `flex` (which I have never used before). Are there alternative solutions other than using `flex`?

Comment: I ended up replacing nested list with spans which was much more simple and clean. Code: `<ul class="list-unstyled"><li>parent element <span style="display: inline-block; margin: 0 10px 0 0;">child element</li></ul>`